# How to set Connection properties on an Apache Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, connection-pooling

I have to set connection properties on an Apache 2.4 Proxy which only uses the ProxyPassRerverse directive instead of the ProxyPass directive which accepts additional parameters like lim, max, ttl, timeout ...

```
  <Location /postbox-sdd/>
    LuaHookTranslateName    /etc/httpd/conf.d/hooks.lua map_xxx_to_postbox early
    ProxyPassReverse        /postbox-sdd/

    Session On
    SessionEnv On
    SessionCookieName cfsession path=/
    SessionCookieName2 session path=/;domain=localhost;httponly;secure;version=1;
    SessionHeader X-Replace-Session

    SetEnv HTTPS on
    RequestHeader edit Destination ^http: https: early

    Header              add     referer "https://postbox.xxx"
    RequestHeader       set     referer "https://postbox.xxx"

    Header              unset CACHE-CONTROL
    RequestHeader       unset CACHE-CONTROL
  </Location>
```

When i try to use the ProxySet directive (for example `ProxySet ttl=20`) after the ProxyPassReverse line i end up with an error because i don't know the worker name. Is there a default worker name or is it possible to set one?

ProxySet can not find 'ttl=20' Worker

The reason for doing this is to use a kind of connection pooling to the destination system postbox.xxx. I want to reuse existing connections for new requests instead of permanent open/close for every new request.

Thanks for help